# Quote 0x API always return Cheeswap: K and code 105

Tags: web3js, 0x

I am making this call to get quote and estimated gas:

https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?sellToken=0x2a9718deff471f3bb91fa0eceab14154f150a385&buyToken=0xe9e7cea3dedca5984780bafc599bd69add087d56&sellAmount=100000000000000&takerAddress=0xB318522DA8aEd77998a5E594040411E7747a4eD5&gasPrice=5000000000

either if I set the gasPrice or not the API is always returning:

```
{
  "code": 105,
  "reason": "Error",
  "values": {
    "message": "CheeseSwap: K"
  }
}
```

Note:
sellToken is Elongate and works with 9 decimals.

I apprecciate you guys can help me to deal with this issue with any other token it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

0x API only supports compliant ERC20 tokens, so tokens with Transfer fees (like ElonGate) are not supported.

Comment: ok got it thanks Jacob, and btw how do I know which kind of token has this transfer fees? or this just by evaluating the contract or something like that?

Comment: Yeah there is no standard to detect it automatically, reading the `transferFrom` function usually gives an indication.